# Explain what &quot means

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't find a clear explanation of what it means when a value/variable is surrounded by '&quot' and why it happens.

For example, I have a simple function which returns an array containing an id.

```
return [params[:id]]
```

For some reason, it returns:

```
[&quot;4&quot;]
```

not:

```
[4]
```

which I would have expected.

Can someone explain what '&quot' is and why/how they are inserted?

Comment: It is an [HTML entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

In HTML, the line `[&quot;4&quot;]` equals `["4"]`.

Comment: The actual response would be `["4"]` not `[4]` since `params` hash holds string values. And then `&quot;` is the translation to HTML of the double quote characters (you must be attempting to output into a web page). See [HTML codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm). Try `return [params[:id].html_safe]` (although I'm not sure of your context here since you haven't really provided any).

Answer (score 11):

**Unicode**

I believe it's something called [unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm) - a standardized way of outputting typography & character sets in digital media. Unicode takes many forms, ASCII being one of the most widely used.

The problem you have, as referred to in the comments, is that as you returned the pure param, you're getting back the string representation of its contents. Whilst the actual contents of the variable will be `["4"]`, HTML will treat it as `[&quot4&quot]`

If you want to output the returned data, you may want to try the [`.raw()][2]` method in your view:

```
<%= raw( [data] ) %>
```

Comment: ASCII isn't a form of unicode, it's a different character set that predates unicode considerably.  In any case, this isn't about unicode.

Comment: Any refs I could look at? Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course.  Actually this Wikipedia page is quite a good place to start --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_information_system_character_sets

Comment: So ASCII dates from the 60s, and in its original form it only really copes with the Latin characters used in the English-speaking world.  Unicode resulted from attempts in the 80s (http://www.unicode.org/history/versionone.html) to create a system that could cope with pretty much any character set known to humankind.

Comment: Oh, as an aside, if you're using Ruby, the following article is a pretty useful explanation of how string encoding works in Ruby 1.9 and above.  http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/ruby-1-9-encodings/

Comment: Thanks bud, will have a look :) Happy holidays!